# How does java continue after an exception?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I've exams on Monday and was therefore doing some preparations. Now I made an exercise to see how exceptions are handled in java.

I've got the following code to analyse:

```
public class ExceptionsExercise {
    private int x;

    private class E1 extends Exception {
        E1() {
            super("exception E1");
        }
    }

    private class E2 extends Exception {
        E2() {
            super("exception E2");
        }
    }

    private class E3 extends Exception {
        E3() {
            super("exception E3");
        }
    }

    public void run() throws E1, E3 {
        try {
            doA();
            System.out.print("3 ");
        } catch (E2 e) {
            System.out.print("4 ");
        } finally {
            System.out.print("5 ");
        }
        System.out.print("6 ");
    }

    public void doA() throws E1, E2, E3 {
        if (x == 1) {
            throw new E1();
        } else if (x == 2) {
            throw new E2();
        } else {
            doB();
            System.out.print("7 ");
        }
    }

    public void doB() throws E3 {
        if (x == 3) {
            System.out.print("8 ");
            throw new E3();
        } else {
            System.out.print("9 ");
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main thisInstance = new Main();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            thisInstance.x = i;
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("x = " + i + " ");
            try {
                thisInstance.run();
            } catch (E1 e) {
                System.out.println("0");
            } catch (E3 e) {

            }
            System.out.println("2 ");
        }
    }
}
```

The question now is what the output is. But with that I had some issues. For example, when an execption is catched in a method, does the method continue normal? Like in the method run() after catching exception e2.

The opposite situation is when a method doesn't catch an exception. Is then just the finally-block executed and then the method breaks. So that in in run() the System.out.print("6 "); is not executed?

Thank you very much

Comment: *The question now is what the output is*: compile and run the code, and you'll see.

Comment: I know the output, that's not my issue. My issue is, that I don't know, how java reacts to these two situations.

Comment: How about analyzing the output and drawing conclusions? How about adding println statements in the code to know more? How about using the debugger to execute the code line by line. These are all simple stuff that you should be able to do by yourself. Or you could read any book or tutorial about exceptions. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: You *do* 'know how Java reacts to these two situations'. The output of your program tells you. Unclear what you're asking,

Comment: Java Language Specification [The try statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20)

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you can run your code to see the results.

> when an execption is catched in a method, does the method continue normal?

Yes. I mean it will be continued farther. For example if doA() throws exception then run() method doesn't print '3'. (but it will prints '5'always because of finally

> Is then just the finally-block executed and then the method breaks. So that in in run() the System.out.print("6 "); is not executed?

Finally block executes always after try block. Was exception or not.

Comment: And what's handled first? The exception throwing to the method where it's called from or the finally-block?

Comment: First will be handled exception in catch block. And after that runs finally block